# View installed packages in Debian

Tags: debian, package-management

I would like to go through a Linux system, and find out what packages have been installed, whether it was with a `.deb` file, or through the `apt` or `dpkg` interface. Is there a common location to find the names of the packages installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to use `dpkg -l` because we are all lazy :)

Comment: Anything for an easy life ;)

Comment: `dpkg-query -W` produces a simpler view, if you need to only know the package and its version.  The problem with `dpkg -l` is that it tries to cram its whole output to the width of your terminal window which often leads to package names trimmed from the right. `dpkg-query` does not have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

From [`Debian Wiki`](https://wiki.debian.org/ListInstalledPackages).

To list the installed packages you can use the following command:

```
dpkg-query -l
```

List the installed packages using a search pattern:

```
dpkg-query -l 'foo*'
```

To check the status of all packages on your system:

```
dpkg -l | more
```

To list the installed packages you can also use the following command (*as mentioned in other answers*):

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

And store the list installed software to a file called `/backup/installed-software.log`:

```
dpkg --get-selections > /backup/installed-software.log
```

It's interesting you look at man [`dpkg-query(1)`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?sektion=1&query=dpkg-query&apropos=0&manpath=sid&locale=en) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

To view installed packages you can use `dpkg -–get-selections`. This will usually be a long list, so filters using `grep` might be used. `dpkg -–get-selections | grep php`

[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/show-the-list-of-installed-packages-on-ubuntu-or-debian/)